# How to select an element from a dropdown using playwright with typescript?

Tags: typescript, playwright

As a beginner I am trying to select an element from a dropdown box using the following code

```
const dropdown = await page1.getByRole('textbox', { name: 'Select' }).click();
await dropdown.selectOption({value: 'slice59'});
```

But it see the property `selectOption` does not exist.

How to do it correctly?

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="custom-autocomplete-targets ivu-select ivu-select-visible ivu-select-single ivu-select-small ivu-form-item-error">
    <div tabindex="-1" class="ivu-select-selection"><input type="hidden">
        <div class="">
            <!---->
            <!----> <span class="" style="display: none;"></span> <input type="text" placeholder="Select" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" class="ivu-select-input">
            <!----> <i class="ivu-icon ivu-icon-ios-arrow-down ivu-select-arrow"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ivu-select-dropdown" style="position: absolute; min-width: 180px; will-change: top, left; transform-origin: center top; top: 135px; left: 339px;" x-placement="bottom-start">
       <ul class="ivu-select-not-found" style="display: none;">
            <li>No matching data</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="ivu-select-dropdown-list">
            <li class="ivu-select-item">
                <div class="custom-select-item-for-preview">5Cells</div>
            </li>
            ... and other li elements
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use selectOption there, you need `<select>` element to use that API.

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-select-option

Check out this answer:
[playwright click a button inside a dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70599536/playwright-click-a-button-inside-a-dropdown/70613883#70613883)

You could use a locator like this:

```
await page.locator(':has-text("5Cells")').click();
```

To click on this item.